# ADFS | User's session expires after 60 minutes even if it is not idle

Tags: adfs

Our web application uses ADFS for authentication. The code works fine by using the valid token received from ADFS and letting authenticated users in to the application.

However, the users tend to get logged out within/after 60 minutes even if they are actively using the application. Since we are not “refreshing” the token or doing  anything with it after the initial authentication, could that be the cause of the session ending abruptly? 
What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas/suggestions.

Thank you.

Sunil